# Why does this Javascript animation display at a different speed on my PC vs my Pixel 6 phone? I'm using delta timing but it's not working

Tags: javascript, animation, game-development, timedelta

**The problem in a nutshell**

Here's a Codepen demo: https://codepen.io/axis80/pen/MWPrPNE?editors=0010. Both sliders should complete an RGB cycle in 30 seconds, however on my Pixel 6 with mobile Chrome browser the smooth-scrolling one at the bottom takes 38 seconds or more.

**More details**

I'm trying to modify SplideJS's smooth scrolling extension so that it will scroll at the same speed on all devices regardless of their framerate.  To that end, I've added some code that implements delta timing, i.e. for each frame it calculates the seconds elapsed since the last frame and multiplies that by the number of pixels to move per second, to determine how far to move in the current frame.

The delta timing does not seem to be working.  If I set it to complete one slide every 10000ms (total of 30000ms for three slides), it works great on my desktop (60fps) and completes the slides in exactly that timeframe.  On my Google Pixel 6 phone (variable fps that is usually 90-120), though, it's significantly slower (38000ms or longer to complete three slides).

I've been going over my code for two days now and I can't see anything wrong. I've dumped the variables to the console and all the calculations it's making seem to check out OK on both desktop and mobile.  It's just running slower on the phone.  Does anyone have any ideas of what might be causing this?

**The code**

```js
  /**
   * Tracks the time that the last frame was rendered.
   */
  let lastRenderTimestamp: number;

  /**
   * Called on every animation frame while the auto scroll is active.
   */
  function move(): void {
    const position    = getPosition();
    const destination = computeDestination( position );

    if ( position !== destination ) {
      translate( destination ); 
      updateIndex( ( currPosition = getPosition() ) );
    } else {
      if ( lastRenderTimestamp ) {
        pause( false );

        if ( autoScrollOptions.rewind ) {
          const speedValue = ( autoScrollOptions.speedMode === 'main' ? options.speed : autoScrollOptions.speed );
          Splide.go( speedValue > 0 ? 0 : Components.Controller.getEnd() );
        }
      }
    }

    throttledUpdateArrows();
    updateLastRenderTimestamp();
  }

  /**
   * Returns the position to move.
   *
   * @param position - The current position.
   *
   * @return A computed destination.
   */
  function computeDestination( position: number ): number {

    let pixelsToMoveThisFrame = 0;
    if ( autoScrollOptions.speedMode === 'main' && lastRenderTimestamp) {
      const elapsedTime = performance.now() - lastRenderTimestamp;
      const pixelsPerSecond = slideSize( null, null ) / options.speed;
      pixelsToMoveThisFrame = pixelsPerSecond * elapsedTime;
    } else {
      pixelsToMoveThisFrame = autoScrollOptions.speed || 1;
    }
    position += orient( pixelsToMoveThisFrame );

    if ( Splide.is( SLIDE ) ) {
      position = clamp( position, getLimit( false ), getLimit( true ) );
    }

    return position;
  }

  /**
   * Moves the slider to the provided position.
   *
   * @param position    - The position to move to.
   * @param preventLoop - Optional. If `true`, sets the provided position as is.
   */
  function translate( position: number, preventLoop?: boolean ): void {
    if ( ! Splide.is( FADE ) ) {
      const destination = preventLoop ? position : loop( position );
      style( list, 'transform', `translate${ resolve( 'X' ) }(${ destination }px)` );
      position !== destination && emit( EVENT_SHIFTED );
    }
  }
```

Here's a screenshot from my Pixel 6 showing a snapshot of the delta calculations:

[image: Screenshot]

I've gone through those calculations by hand and they all seem spot on to me.

Here's a bonus Github issue with more details: https://github.com/Splidejs/splide-extension-auto-scroll/issues/10

Any ideas?